# Iteration Url Load from CSV in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Please Help me
I have a data url in the CSV file, in that file there are 100 rows and 1 column,
I want to load data line 1 to line 100 from CSV using Python, how do I write the code line?

However, after running the repetition can only work once in one of the lines does not reach the end of the url in the CSV and does not continue to the next URL.

```
disc_information = html.find('div', class_='alert alert-info global-promo').text.strip().strip('\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

how do I get through if an error occurs when html is not found?

the following line of code I use python, please help so that the looping scrape runs to the end of the url list

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import pandas


with open('Url Torch.csv','rt') as f:
  data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  for row in data:
      URL_GO = row[2]

def variable_Scrape(url):
    try:
        cookies = dict(cookie="............")
        request = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
        html = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
        title = html.find('div', class_='title').text.strip().strip('\n')
        desc = html.find('div', class_='content').text
        link = html.find_all('img', class_='lazyload slide-item owl-lazy')
        normal_price = html.find('div', class_='amount public').text.strip().strip('\n')
        disc_information = html.find('div', class_='alert alert-info global-promo').text.strip().strip('\n')

    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
        #ConnectionAbortedError
        return False
    else:
        print(title)
        #print(desc)
        #print(link)
    finally:
        print(title)
        print(desc)
        print(link)
        print('Finally.....')
variable_Scrape(URL_GO)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What specifically is the issue? There are already resources available on how to catch and handle errors. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Is hard to give you the exact answer without seeing you csv file but try this:

```
import csv

f = open('you_file.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
  print row[0]
```

Comment: thats oke, but for looping from csv only work for 1 row,  code was update

Answer (score 0):

This is the code

```
import csv

data = []  #create an empty list to store rows on it
with open('emails.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row) #add each row to the list
```

Based on your comments about passing a loop when the url is not ok:

```
for url in data:   # data is the list where url stored
    try:
        # do your code here (requests, beautifulsoup) :
        # r = requests.get(url) ...
    except:
        pass
        # will go to the next loop (next url) if an error happens
```

Comment: OK I will, but need more clarification :you have collection of urls in your csv file and you want to scrape each of them through a loop using requests and beautifulsoup ?  Also, is your csv file containing a header?

Comment: problem is done, but current a new problem,
thisi is problem

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\**\*\*V-1.0 .py", line 51, in <module>
    print(-----)
NameError: name '-------' is not defined

how to skip if error that?

Comment: for the url looping problem of the CSV file is complete, but when looping runs on one of the url lines, there are parts of the html element that are not present but are parsed with the python variable so that an error occurs:

Comment: name 'NameError' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
   The file "e: \ path .py", line 51, in <module>
     print (NameError)
NameError: name 'NameError' is not defined

Comment: I want to ask,
how to pass parsing html elements that are not found, so that the parsing process goes to the next command.

Comment: I added the solution to my post above, check it. If ok let me know